# Login page so wide

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login, account

Please i need help, i have been battling with this for hours now and i still cant get it right, please help me, the login page is so wide i cant get it to be normal.

This is the user login page on my wordpress and this is the screenshot attached below, please help me anyone if you can

[image: wordpress user login error]

Comment: Hi Tina, welcome! Please read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You did not provide any code or some info on your setup. Even if we wanted to, we can't help you. Please note, including a link to your site and asking us to fix it for you is also not accepted here, sorry. Try to reformat your question, include all info on your current site (theme, page builder beeing used?, is it WOO login page?). Many many questions ;-)

Comment: Also it sounds like some css is making it wide.  Impossible to tell without a link to the site.  Lookup using 'inspect element' features of browsers like firefox.  This will help you see what css/html is making it wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you would need to understand how to ask question in here.
Why login page is wide, these would be for some below reasons.

- When you install wordpress plugins, it changed default wordpress style
- You could solve these problems by making input fields responsive
  using css
- Don't forget to read documentation of plugins that you used in your
  website